# Web caching in windows application causing a delay for application loading

Tags: c#

In my C# windows application

i have this sample c# class
 public class clsRslCache
    {
        private Cache oCache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
    }

i create an instance of this class in the main method , during the launch of the application it causes the delay of about 2-3 minutes and then on subsequent request it loads the application instantly .

I am not sure why is the delay happening for the first time .If i wait for 5 min on the machine dont end up doing anything on it and the next time i start my windows application it shows the same behaviour.

Does anybody have any idea about it.

*Note :you need to reference System.web.dll in your windows application.

Thanks

Comment: I think if you wait till the HttpRuntime is up and running before accessing HttpRuntime.Cache it'll be a lot faster.  My guess is you're forcing an early initialization of the the http server.  (If you're not already running an http server in your app, then wherever you first call it will have to do this initialization)

Comment: could you please explain your statement  by a pseudo code.Also the machine doesnt have iis installed . and i am trying to use caching mechanism in c# windows application

Answer (score 0):

Okay, assuming HttpRuntime.Cache is the only thing you're using from ASP.Net:

HttpRuntime's class description from MSDN:

> Provides a set of ASP.NET run-time services for the current
>   application.

So, there's a little part of a web server living in System.web.dll and this is one main API for accessing it.  The first time you make a call into System.web.dll things will have to be initialized, which takes some time (although minutes is surprising 10 - 20 seconds seems more likely).

One thing you could try is initializing in a sub-thread:

```
volatile bool isCacheReady = false;
Cache cache = null;
System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() {
    cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
    isCacheReady = true;
});
t1.Start();

// periodically check if cache is available yet (not here in this thread though):
if( isCacheReady )
{
    // do something with cache
}
```

Of course, that still means your app won't have caching for those 2-3 minutes but at least it shouldn't block start-up.  (And I should look deeper, because 2-3 minutes seems too long, there should be a way to speed it up or use another caching tool with less overhead)

Comment: thanks for the recommendation but still wanted to know the reason of 2-3 min delay and it happens only with a particular client of mine .is it due to some network or firewall setting that this call is taking that much time.